# Cordova browser platform refresh

Tags: cordova

Is there a way that I do not re run "cordova run browser", but I just refresh the page after I make changes to my js code? It would be faster to just press F5 on the browser.

Thank you

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve it??

Comment: unfortunately not. I recompile every time :-(

Comment: You mean use ionic build tools without actually using the ionic libraries and  page structure? (I am asking this because I use a custom MVC pattern that  is easier for me to understand and organise code).

Comment: Actually, this is not working for me. In fact I make the change, I run the cordova run browser command again and it still does not apply the change, I close the browser and everything, but it is not reflected. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 21):

[Cordova Browser-Sync Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-browsersync) make exactly this.

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-browsersync
$ cordova run browser -- --live-reload
```

F5 will be refresh content after editing.

Comment: Please don't just post a link to some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks, hope the editing post more informatively, but why downvote?

Comment: This now seems to be an old repository that no longer works.

Comment: yeah it doesnt work, like react does react also has some auto live reload stuff but im not yet familiar that much with cordova.